# group function using takeWhile and dropWhile

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner in Haskell. I'd like to define the function `group` defined in the module `Data.List`. What I have done is this:

```
group []=[]

group (x:xs)=(x:[]):lista xs
```

However, it doesn't result when we have equal letters together. How do I do that part? If possible using `dropWhile` and `takeWhile`.

Comment: What does your function `lista` do?

Comment: What is `lista`?  I can also see that the output will always start with a list of length 1, because of the `(x:[])`....  This is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

hint

```
group :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
group [] = []
group xs@(x:_) = -- what should be here?  
      where (f,s) = (takeWhile (==x) xs, dropWhile (==x) xs)
```